# python - Iterating over multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iteration, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I´m trying to iterate over a huge pandas dataframe (over 370.000 rows) based on the index.

For each row the code should look back on the last 12 entries of this index (if available) and sum up based on (running) quarters / semesters / year.

If there is no information or not enough information (only last 3 months) then the code should consider the other months / quarters as 0.

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

[image]

This is the expected output:

[image]

So looking at DateID "1" we don´t have any other information for this row. DateID "1" is the last month in this case (month 12 so to say) and therefore in Q4 and H2. All other previous month are not existing and therefore not considered.

I already found a working solution but its very inefficient and takes a huge amount of time that is not acceptable.

Here is my code sample:

```
for company_name, c in df.groupby('Account Name'):
    for i, row in c.iterrows():
        i += 1
        if i < 4:              
            q4 = c.iloc[:i]['Value$'].sum()
            q3 = 0
            q2 = 0
            q1 = 0
            h2 = q4 + q3
            h1 = q2 + q1
            year = q4 + q3 + q2 + q1

        elif 3 < i < 7:
            q4 = c.iloc[i-3:i]['Value$'].sum()
            q3 = c.iloc[:i-3]['Value$'].sum()
            q2 = 0
            q1 = 0
            h2 = q4 + q3
            h1 = q2 + q1
            year = q4 + q3 + q2 + q1

        elif 6 < i < 10:
            q4 = c.iloc[i-3:i]['Value$'].sum()
            q3 = c.iloc[i-6:i-3]['Value$'].sum()
            q2 = c.iloc[:i-6]['Value$'].sum()
            q1 = 0
            h2 = q4 + q3
            h1 = q2 + q1
            year = q4 + q3 + q2 + q1
        elif 9 < i < 13:
            q4 = c.iloc[i-3:i]['Value$'].sum()
            q3 = c.iloc[i-6:i-3]['Value$'].sum()
            q2 = c.iloc[i-9:i-6]['Value$'].sum()
            q1 = c.iloc[:i-9]['Value$'].sum()
            h2 = q4 + q3
            h1 = q2 + q1
            year = q4 + q3 + q2 + q1
        else:
            q4 = c.iloc[i-3:i]['Value$'].sum()
            q3 = c.iloc[i-6:i-3]['Value$'].sum()
            q2 = c.iloc[i-9:i-6]['Value$'].sum()
            q1 = c.iloc[i-12:i-9]['Value$'].sum()
            h2 = q4 + q3
            h1 = q2 + q1
            year = q4 + q3 + q2 + q1

        new_df = new_df.append({'Account Name':row['Account Name'], 'DateID': row['DateID'],'Q4':q4,'Q3':q3,'Q2':q2,'Q1':q1,'H1':h1,'H2':h2,'Year':year},ignore_index=True)
```

As I said I´m looking for a more efficient way to calculate these numbers as I have almost 10.000 Account Names and 30 Date ID´s per Account.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think, you don't have to loop in that case. Did I get it right, that your `DateID` is unique within each `Account Name` and represents one month?

Comment: Yes exactly! It is the already summed up Value$ for each DateID / Month

Comment: And your quarters are just 3 months periods, they only start releative to the current row, not from a fixed date (so not always from jan-march), right?

Comment: Also correct! We assume it to be a "rolling" quarter! E.g. Current month / row is May so Q4 is May, April and March

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right, this should calculate your figures:

```
grouped= df.groupby('Account Name')['Value$']
last_3= grouped.apply(lambda ser: ser.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).sum())
last_6= grouped.apply(lambda ser: ser.rolling(window=6, min_periods=1).sum())
last_9= grouped.apply(lambda ser: ser.rolling(window=9, min_periods=1).sum())
last_12= grouped.apply(lambda ser: ser.rolling(window=12, min_periods=1).sum())

df['Q4']= last_3
df['Q3']= last_6  - last_3
df['Q2']= last_9  - last_6
df['Q1']= last_12 - last_9
df['H1']= df['Q1'] + df['Q2']
df['H2']= df['Q3'] + df['Q4']
```

This outputs:

```
Out[19]: 
   Account Name  DateID  Value$     Q4     Q3     Q2     Q1     H1     H2
0             A       0      33   33.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   33.0
1             A       1      20   53.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   53.0
2             A       2      24   77.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   77.0
3             A       3      21   65.0   33.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   98.0
4             A       4      22   67.0   53.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  120.0
5             A       5      31   74.0   77.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  151.0
6             A       6      30   83.0   65.0   33.0    0.0   33.0  148.0
7             A       7      23   84.0   67.0   53.0    0.0   53.0  151.0
8             A       8      11   64.0   74.0   77.0    0.0   77.0  138.0
9             A       9      35   69.0   83.0   65.0   33.0   98.0  152.0
10            A      10      32   78.0   84.0   67.0   53.0  120.0  162.0
11            A      11      31   98.0   64.0   74.0   77.0  151.0  162.0
12            A      12      32   95.0   69.0   83.0   65.0  148.0  164.0
13            A      13      20   83.0   78.0   84.0   67.0  151.0  161.0
14            A      14      15   67.0   98.0   64.0   74.0  138.0  165.0
15            B       0      44   44.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   44.0
16            B       1      43   87.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   87.0
17            B       2      31  118.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  118.0
18            B       3      10   84.0   44.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  128.0
19            B       4      13   54.0   87.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  141.0
20            B       5      20   43.0  118.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  161.0
21            B       6      28   61.0   84.0   44.0    0.0   44.0  145.0
22            B       7      14   62.0   54.0   87.0    0.0   87.0  116.0
23            B       8      20   62.0   43.0  118.0    0.0  118.0  105.0
24            B       9      41   75.0   61.0   84.0   44.0  128.0  136.0
25            B      10      39  100.0   62.0   54.0   87.0  141.0  162.0
26            B      11      46  126.0   62.0   43.0  118.0  161.0  188.0
27            B      12      26  111.0   75.0   61.0   84.0  145.0  186.0
28            B      13      24   96.0  100.0   62.0   54.0  116.0  196.0
29            B      14      34   84.0  126.0   62.0   43.0  105.0  210.0
32            C       2      12   12.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   12.0
33            C       3      15   27.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   27.0
34            C       4      45   72.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   72.0
35            C       5      22   82.0   12.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   94.0
36            C       6      48  115.0   27.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  142.0
37            C       7      45  115.0   72.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  187.0
38            C       8      11  104.0   82.0   12.0    0.0   12.0  186.0
39            C       9      27   83.0  115.0   27.0    0.0   27.0  198.0
```

For the following test data:

```
data= {'Account Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
 'DateID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 'Value$': [33, 20, 24, 21, 22, 31, 30, 23, 11, 35, 32, 31, 32, 20, 15, 44, 43, 31, 10, 13, 20, 28, 14, 20, 41, 39, 46, 26, 24, 34, 12, 15, 45, 22, 48, 45, 11, 27]
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Edit:**: If you want to count the unique entires over the same period, you can do that as follows:

```
def get_nunique(np_array):
    unique, counts= np.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)
    return len(unique)

df['Category'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(get_nunique)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! Very smart! I didn´t know about the "rolling" function!

Comment: Yes it's a very handy function.

Comment: I came accross another "issue" or question: What if DateID is not unique per Account Name? Just thinking about anotherr column where we can see the "category" some values appeared in. So e.g. for your first line
DateID = 0,
Value = 33,
Account Name  = A,
but this is split up to
DateID = 0,
Value = 20,
Account Name = A,
Category = First 
+ DateID = 0
Value = 13
Account Name  = A
Category = Second. The goal now would be to count the "NUNIQUE" Categories for the last 3 months and the last 6 @jottbe

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean. Do you want to sum up all records with the ids of the last 3 month's per category-Account Name combination or still have one line per Account Name which sums up the rows for all categories? The first could be solved by adding the category column to the `groupby` (just recognized I forgot to put it in my answer above :-)

Comment: The second variant would be a bit more complicated, if you need to propagate the result back to your original dataframe. Please let me know, which one you need.

Comment: Its the second variant! At the end I want to have one line per "Account Name" / "DateID" combination where I can see how many unique categories someone bought in the last 3 months / 6 months (always rolling).

Comment: Ah ok, the unique entries. And you only need them for the last 3 / last 6 months not quarterwise, right? (quarterwise like above with Q1-Q4 would be more difficult).

Comment: Last 3 and last 6 yes! :-)

Comment: I just added a version for 3 months, hope that helps.

Comment: This is not working as it only looks at the last 3 lines. With the categories it is possible that we have, e.g. 10 lines for the last 3 date ids!

Comment: Ah I see. I think for that part you can't work with rolling, because for some reason, it only supports numeric values. Btw. I think we are already far from the original question. Maybe you can open another one?!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to overload the answer above completely, so I add a new one for your second part:

```
# define a function that
# creates the unique counts
# by aggregating period_length times
# so 3 times for the quarter mapping
# and 6 times for the half year
# it's basically doing something like
# a sliding window aggregation
def get_mapping(df, period_lenght=3):
    df_mapping= None
    for offset in range(period_lenght):
        quarter= (df['DateID']+offset) // period_lenght
        aggregated= df.groupby([quarter, df['Account Name']]).agg({'DateID': max, 'Category': lambda ser: len(set(ser))})
        incomplete_data= ((aggregated['DateID']+offset+1)//period_lenght <= aggregated.index.get_level_values(0)) & (aggregated.index.get_level_values(0) >= period_lenght)
        aggregated.drop(aggregated.index[incomplete_data].to_list(), inplace=True)
        aggregated.set_index('DateID', append=True, inplace=True)
        aggregated= aggregated.droplevel(0, axis='index')
        if df_mapping is None:
            df_mapping= aggregated
        else:
            df_mapping= pd.concat([df_mapping, aggregated], axis='index')
    return df_mapping

# apply it for 3 months and merge it to the source df
df_mapping= get_mapping(df, period_lenght=3)
df_mapping.columns= ['unique_3_months']    
df_with_3_months= df.merge(df_mapping, left_on=['Account Name', 'DateID'], how='left', right_index=True)

# do the same for 6 months and merge it again
df_mapping= get_mapping(df, period_lenght=6)
df_mapping.columns= ['unique_6_months']
df_with_6_months= df_with_3_months.merge(df_mapping, left_on=['Account Name', 'DateID'], how='left', right_index=True)
```

This results in:

```
Out[305]: 
   Account Name  DateID  Value$  Category  unique_3_months  unique_6_months
0             A       0      10         1                1                1
1             A       1      12         2                2                2
2             A       1      38         1                2                2
3             A       2      20         3                3                3
4             A       3      25         3                3                3
5             A       4      24         4                2                4
6             A       5      27         8                3                5
7             A       6      30         5                3                6
8             A       7      47         7                3                5
9             A       8      30         4                3                5
10            A       9      17         7                2                4
11            A      10      20         8                3                4
12            A      11      33         8                2                4
13            A      12      45         9                2                4
14            A      13      19         2                3                5
15            A      14      24        10                3                3
15            A      14      24        10                3                4
15            A      14      24        10                3                4
15            A      14      24        10                3                5
15            A      14      24        10                3                1
15            A      14      24        10                3                2
16            B       0      41         2                1                1
17            B       1      13         9                2                2
18            B       2      17         6                3                3
19            B       3      45         7                3                4
20            B       4      11         6                2                4
21            B       5      38         8                3                5
22            B       6      44         8                2                4
23            B       7      15         8                1                3
24            B       8      50         2                2                4
25            B       9      27         7                3                4
26            B      10      38        10                3                4
27            B      11      25         6                3                5
28            B      12      25         8                3                5
29            B      13      14         7                3                5
30            B      14      25         9                3                3
30            B      14      25         9                3                4
30            B      14      25         9                3                5
30            B      14      25         9                3                5
30            B      14      25         9                3                1
30            B      14      25         9                3                2
31            C       2      31         9                1                1
32            C       3      31         7                2                2
33            C       4      26         5                3                3
34            C       5      11         2                3                4
35            C       6      15         8                3                5
36            C       7      22         2                2                5
37            C       8      33         2                2                4
38            C       9      16         5                2                3
38            C       9      16         5                2                3
38            C       9      16         5                2                3
38            C       9      16         5                2                1
38            C       9      16         5                2                2
38            C       9      16         5                2                2
```

The output is based on the following input data:

```
data= {
       'Account Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       'DateID': [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       'Value$': [10, 12, 38, 20, 25, 24, 27, 30, 47, 30, 17, 20, 33, 45, 19, 24, 41, 13, 17, 45, 11, 38, 44, 15, 50, 27, 38, 25, 25, 14, 25, 31, 31, 26, 11, 15, 22, 33, 16],
       'Category': [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 2, 10, 2, 9, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 8, 2, 7, 10, 6, 8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 2, 8, 2, 2, 5]
}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I hope that is what you wanted. Viele Grüße aus Stuttgart.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this new idea about the second issue!
Viele Grüße aus München!